# Regex credit / payment card number tests - removing dashes and spaces

Tags: regex

I need to alert on payment cards (Visa, Mastercard and Amex) in emails, but also need to allow for spaces and dashes.

So far I have this which works:

`\b4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13})\b`

But I want to find and ignore consecutive dashes and spaces before or whilst using the above. I know this does that:

`\b[ -]+\b`

So how do I combine the two into one Regex please?

**Edit:
Answer** is to use a don't capture expression `(?:[ -]*)` after every character. Makes it long but it works:

`\b4(?:[ -]*)([0-9](?:[ -]*)){12}(?:([0-9](?:[ -]*)){3})?|(?:5(?:[ -]*)[1-5](?:[ -]*)([0-9](?:[ -]*)){2}|2(?:[ -]*)2(?:[ -]*)2(?:[ -]*)[1-9](?:[ -]*)|2(?:[ -]*)2(?:[ -]*)[3-9](?:[ -]*)[0-9](?:[ -]*)|2(?:[ -]*)[3-6](?:[ -]*)([0-9](?:[ -]*)){2}|2(?:[ -]*)7(?:[ -]*)[01](?:[ -]*)[0-9](?:[ -]*)|2(?:[ -]*)7(?:[ -]*)2(?:[ -]*)0(?:[ -]*))([0-9](?:[ -]*)){12}|3(?:[ -]*)[47](?:[ -]*)([0-9](?:[ -]*)){13}\b`

Comment: Try this: `(<regex1>|<regex2)`

Comment: @AndersonPimentel thanks but that would simply match both credit card numbers and the --- in the string "rubbish---rubbish". I want the credit card matching to happen after stripping out consecutive spaces or dashes.

Comment: regexes don't concatenate individual matches. You need some environment around regex that provides such a feature. You say that `\b[ -]+\b` ignores spaces and dashes, but that is not exactly true: that **matches** them, and you seem to have some way to act upon that by replacing matches with an empty string or something similar. Please clarify what technology you use.

Comment: @trincot sadly no technology. This is a regex matching string we can put in Mimecast to find card numbers in emails and block them leaving.
You second point noted but I believe I need a "don't capture" group for spaces or dashes but I don't know how to add it to my string. The group would probably look like this:
(?:[ -]+)

Comment: To be clear, I don't need to do a replace just an "ignore dashes and spaces"

Comment: Answer is to use a don't capture expression (?:[ -]*) after every character. Makes it long but it works. Question edited to include the answer.